# Matrix calculations

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

Now I have something like this:
$$p\beta^T\beta+q\beta^TX^TX\beta$$
where p and q are constants and $\beta$, X are matrices. I want to do something like this:
$$\beta^2(p+qX^2)$$
Is this right?

My thought is that since $\beta X^TX\beta$ is just $(\beta X)^2$, so this is ok.

If this is wrong, can anybody tell me what is the right way to do a similar thing like extracting $\beta$?

Please help! I don't know where I can find any formulas for this.

Comment: Do you mean to say that you think those two expressions are equal? They are not. In particular, in general $A^TA\ne A^2$ and $(AB)^2\ne A^2B^2$

Comment: I don't think you can really simplify this expression other than writing it like $\beta^T(pI+qX^TX)\beta$ or $p\beta^T\beta + q (X\beta)^T(X\beta)$. Note that $\beta^2$ and $X^2$ might not even be well defined if $\beta$ and $X$ are not square. Moreover, matrix multiplication doesn't commute so you can't rearrage things the way you have.

Comment: I think you might need to add some context. It is not generally true that $(\beta X)^2=\beta X^TX\beta$. If this is the case, then there must be some additional information missing here.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to extract $\beta$, you need to extract it to behind the parenthesis. @tch is right. Also note that, only $||X||^2_2 = X^TX$